# How to make data saved in database expire after a time period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, database-design, model

I'm building a store in rails. A store has orders, order_items, users..

Right now when customer adds order_item to a cart, order with unique id is created automatically, and order_items are saved under order_items model. There is also validation saying that only 3 order_items are allowed in one order.

If possible, I would like to remove those order_items that are saved to a model after 30 days. 30 days counter should start after saving 3 order_items.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  validates_length_of :order_items, maximum: 3 #only 3 order_items are allowed within an order for each user
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal



  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end



end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  validates_associated :order
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present


  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end


end
```

order_items_controller.rb

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.user_id = current_user.id
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id


  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
  end
end



  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end



  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end


private

  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)

 end
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.decimal  "unit_price",  precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "total_price", precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.boolean  "has_ordered"
  end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "subtotal",             precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "tax",                  precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "shipping",             precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "total",                precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.integer  "order_status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "ordered"
    t.date     "first_item_added_at"
    t.date     "first_order_added_at"
  end
```

Comment: Run a background job that checks the timestamp of an item added to a cart and removes any over 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

One common way of approaching this problem is having a background process periodically checking the database and doing any maintenance work necessary (cleaning, calculating some intermediate results, etc.).

One simplistic solution that checks orders with at least 3 order items and deletes the items that are older than 30 days is below.

With rails you could put the following under `config/initializers/order_cleaner.rb`, then it gets loaded every time you start your Rails application.

```
Thread.new do
  while true
    # Get all orders with at least 3 order_items
    orders = Orders.joins(:order_items).group('orders.id').having('count(order_id) >= 3')
    orders.each do |o|
      # Delete associated order_item if it's older than 30 days
      o.order_items.each {|oi| oi.destroy! if oi.updated_at < 30.days.ago }
    end
    sleep 1.minute
  end
end
```

Couple notes:

1. If the *Orders* table gets bigger, it would be practical to do everything in database without creating the ActiveRecord model instances and separate queries for every *OrderItem*
2. For more complicated scheduling and job retrying using [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) or [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is worth considering
3. More sophisticated solution would require cleanup thread, some logging and taking care that multiple instances don't get started (e.g. when you're using Unicorn to load balance your app)

Comment: I tried testing this code by placing 2.minutes.ago instead of 30.days.ago and items are not being removed..